# Casting parameter-less generic lambda to a function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to cast a parameter-less generic lambda to a function pointer. This problem generally applies to generic lambdas, which parameters don't depend on the template argument.

Example tries to cast the lambda with one parameter (`int`) which is typewise independent of the template parameter `T`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []<class T>(int v) -> void
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ' ' << static_cast<T>(v) << '\n';
    };

    // How do I cast lambda to a function pointer that uses operator(int)<char>
    // This doesn't compile, I've reached this conclusion after examining this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
    auto seeked_ptr_char = lambda.operator fptr_t<char>();

    // Hacky solution :(
    auto mptr_char = &decltype(lambda)::operator()<char>;
    decltype(mptr_char) mptr_float = &decltype(lambda)::operator()<float>;

    (lambda.*mptr_char)(48);
    (lambda.*mptr_float)(52);

    // This is okay (tho parameter is dependent on a template argument, which is not what we are looking for)
    auto another_lambda = []<class T>(T v) -> void
    {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    };

    void(*ptr_char)(char) = another_lambda;
    ptr_char(50);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't compile with
`x86-64 gcc 12.1 with -std=c++20 -O3`

`x86-64 clang 14.0.0 -std=c++20 -O3`

https://godbolt.org/z/cavbT5jM3

Comment: "*According to original proposal and cppreference this should work?*" According to whom?

Comment: There's something very important that's missing from your question: a question. I searched far and wide, and I completely failed to uncover anything other than a general description of your current task. Ok, and? What's the question? The shown code doesn't compile with some error? Compiles and runs fine for me, with gcc 12 and `-std=c++20`. I have no idea what the question is, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've updated the code snippet, it should be clearer now.

Comment: @NicolBolas *According to* wasn't a proper wording here. I've meant *the conclusion I've reached by examining cppreference and original proposal*.

Comment: "*This problem generally applies to generic lambdas, which parameters don't depend on the template argument.*" Why would you write such a thing? The only way to call it is with `.operator()<...>` syntax. Why would you want to do that? Like, is creating a named function outside of the code really that bad, compared to having to use `.operator()<>` to call it?

Comment: Well, yes, it's clearer now. But, as I mentioned, this compiles just fine for me, with gcc12 and `--std=c++20`. You should also update your question again and specify which compiler, and also mention the fact that you have on good authority that gcc is happy as a clam, with this. Questions about different behavior from different compilers are free karma.

Comment: This does not compile on clang or gcc. I've posted a link to godbolt in the question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm trying to cast a non-capturing generic lambda to a function pointer, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @MarcinPoloczek: But why? What's the point of trying to do a thing that serves no purpose? You're working with a lambda that nobody should ever write. What's the point of talking about its behavior?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not debating that someone should write that, but it should be possible to cast it to function pointer since it doesn't violate the rules necessary for such conversion.

Comment: @MarcinPoloczek: "*it doesn't violate the rules necessary for such conversion.*" Why do you think this is the case?

Comment: @NicolBolas *This user-defined conversion function is only defined if the capture list of the lambda-expression is empty. It is a public, constexpr, (since C++17) non-virtual, non-explicit, const noexcept member function of the closure object.* This is what cppreference says.

Comment: *A generic captureless lambda has a user-defined conversion function template with the same invented template parameter list as the function-call operator template.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I cast lambda to a function pointer that uses `operator(int)<char>`

TL;DR: you don't.

First, function pointers point to functions. Templates are not *functions* yet; a function template only becomes a function when you supply it with template parameters. A function pointer can point to a specific instantiation of a function template. But it cannot point to a function template.

The conversion from a generic lambda to a function pointer relies on invoking a template conversion functions. As such, the lambda effectively has a conversion function like this:

```
using func = void(int);

template<typename T>
operator func*();
```

However, that's a template conversion function. And since the type being converted to does not supply the template parameter, in order to call that function, you must *explicitly* provide that type. Which means you have to explicitly call the conversion function.

But given the code you wrote, you worked all of that out. Which means your real problem is:

> How do I explicitly invoke a template conversion function if the result of the conversion is in no way related to the template parameter(s)?

Lambdas don't matter here. This is all about calling a special kind of template conversion function.

And the answer is... apparently, you *don't*.

You can explicitly invoke a conversion function to the type `type_name` via `object_name.operator type_name()` syntax. The problem is [this line in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.conv.fct#3.sentence-2):

> The conversion-type-id in a conversion-function-id is the longest sequence of tokens that could possibly form a conversion-type-id.

The problem is how `lambda.operator fptr_t<char>()` gets parsed. See, `fptr_t` *could be* the name of a template class. And therefore, `fptr_t<char>` *could be* the name of a specialization of that class template. Therefore `fptr_t<char>` is "the longest sequence of tokens that **could possibly** form a conversion-type-id".

In short, the compiler thinks you're trying to invoke the conversion function to the type `fptr_t<char>`. It *does not matter* that `fptr_t` is not a template, and the compiler can look around and figure that out. Parsing happens *before* any of that kind of thinking. So the parsing rules take priority. The entire `fptr_t<char>` text is taken as the typename for the conversion function.

This all means that, unless the template parameter(s) for a conversion function can be deduced from the type being converted to alone, it appears that it is *impossible* to call such a conversion function. Such a conversion function can *exist*; you can declare such functions just fine. But C++ lacks any syntax for actually interacting with it.

Yet another reason why lambdas with template parameters that cannot be deduced from the function arguments are not especially useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Nicol pointing it out, my solution is not a function pointer. It needs more edition..

---

You can convert it to a `std::function` through another lambda function as a wrapper, I have no idea how it can be further converted to a function pointer though,

```cpp
auto wrapper = []<typename T, typename F>(F&& f) {
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) {
        f.template operator()<T>(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
};

std::function<void(int)> ptr_char = wrapper.operator()<char>(lambda);

ptr_char(48);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ez4dj1bYq)

Comment: He asked how to convert it to a function pointer, not how to call it.

Comment: I thought since the return type is a non-templated lambda, it can be converted to a function pointer..?

Comment: But the inner lambda has a capture and therefore cannot be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.